# If $x,y$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$, then $||x|-|y|| \le |x|-|y|$

Tags: real-analysis

If $x,y$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$, then $||x|-|y|| \le |x|-|y|$

I'm supposed to justify the previous statement by citing a theorem, giving a proof, or giving a counterexample.

The following is a proof of the statement.

$|x| = ||x|| = ||x|-|y|+|y|| = ||x|-|y||+||y|| \le |x|$.

Therefore, $||x|-|y|| \le |x| - |y|$

I would like to know if this is sufficient, and how this proof can be improved.

Comment: What if $x=1$ and $y=2$?

Comment: The LHS is nonnegative because of the absolut value, while the RHS is negative for $|x|<|y|$. Therefore, you can easily see that it can't be true.

Comment: Then it's false. Where did I go wrong with the reasoning?

Comment: On the first line of your proof the second $=$ sign should be $\le$. Using $=$ was what allowed you to conclude that the final $\le$ was true.

Comment: I see now. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by Dr. Sonnhard Graubner, the statement

$\vert \vert x \vert - \vert y \vert \vert \le \vert x \vert - \vert y \vert \tag 1$

is false.  A similar ***looking*** statement,

$\vert \vert x \vert - \vert y \vert \vert \le \vert x - y \vert, \tag 2$

is however true, and the proof ***looks*** similar to what was given in the text of the question:

$x = y + (x - y); \tag 3$

$\vert x \vert = \vert y + (x - y) \vert \le \vert y \vert + \vert x - y \vert, \tag 4$

by the ***triangle inequality*** ($\vert x + y \vert \le \vert x \vert + \vert y \vert$); thus

$\vert x \vert - \vert y \vert \le \vert x - y \vert; \tag 5$

interchanging the roles of $x$ and $y$ we see that

$\vert y \vert - \vert x \vert \le \vert y - x \vert; \tag 6$

noting that $\vert x - y \vert = \vert y - x \vert$ we thus, from (5) and (6) obtain

$-\vert x - y \vert = -\vert y - x \vert \le \vert x \vert - \vert y \vert \le \vert x - y \vert, \tag 7$

which is equivalent to

$\vert \vert x \vert - \vert y \vert \vert \le \vert x - y \vert. \tag 8$

This result is sometimes known as the ***reverse triangle inequality***.

Perhaps our OP was reaching for something along these lines.

Answer (score 2):

Just substitute $$x=1,y=4$$ then we get
$$|1-4|\le 1-4$$?

Answer (score 2):

The true inequality (valid for all $x,y$) is
$$\bigl||x|-|y|\bigr|\le|x-y|.$$

On the contrary, 
we have $$\bigl||x|-|y|\bigr|\ge |x|-|y|.$$

Comment: Shouldn't the first line be $\le$?

Comment: @JohnDouma: Yes, of course. Thanks for pointing it!

Comment: @Bernard Hi, Can you visit my recent question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2709512/how-i-must-solve-a-pde-to-find-a-bundle-mathcalf-of-parallel-planes?

Comment: @Sebastiano: I've looked at your question (now deleted). I'd love to help, but unfortunately, I know very few things about PDE's (I'm mainly an algebraist).

Comment: @Bernard Can I talk to you in a chat, so I'll explain? Where do we write to?

Comment: @Sebastiano: It's possible if you know how to open a chat.